# FastApi my get_current_user function can't get user data after set jwt token in cookie

Tags: python, python-3.x, jwt, fastapi

After set my jwt token in cookie I can't get user data from my get_current_user function.

here is my login function:

```
@router.post("/login")
def user_login(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(),db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.mobile_number==form_data.username).first()
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail='wrong phone number or password')
    if not verify_password(form_data.password, user.password):
        raise HTTPException(400, detail='wrong phone number or password')
    # Create the tokens and passing to set_access_cookies or set_refresh_cookies
    access_token = Authorize.create_access_token(subject=user.username)
    refresh_token = Authorize.create_refresh_token(subject=user.username)

   # Set the JWT cookies in the response
   Authorize.set_access_cookies(access_token)
   Authorize.set_refresh_cookies(refresh_token)

   return {"status":"success"}
```

here is my get_current_user function:

```
async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme),db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        #headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},  
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        mobile_number: str = payload.get("sub")
        if mobile_number is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = schemas.TokenData(mobile_number=mobile_number)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.mobile_number==mobile_number).first()
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user
```

before set my token in cookies I can access my user attribute using my  get_current_user function like `get_current_user.id`, `get_current_user.mobile_number` but now I can't.

Comment: This seems to be the same question you asked earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73934222/fast-api-how-to-get-user-id-and-others-user-attribute-when-using-authjwt - you received a few comments as well, but didn't provide any additional information.

Comment: @MatsLindh it's completely different question.

Comment: Could it be that you are comparing a phone number to a username? `models.User.mobile_number==form_data.username`. And what is `Authorize`?